# Loading custom cell from nib does not finish on time

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UIView that contains two UITableViews, which are toggled between using a segmented control in the navigation bar of the UIView.

The first table (ingredients) uses only standard cells, and is working fine.

The second table (recipes) uses a custom cell loaded from a nib. The problem is that when the app is launched and the recipes table was last visible (from state preservation), when the view appears the cells are presented using standard cells. If the user cycles the mentioned segmented control, they appear as intended upon return to the recipes table.

The relevant parts of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in the viewcontroller:

```
// Check that we are displaying the right table
if (tableView == self.recipesTable) {
    static NSString *recipeCellIdentifier = @"RecipeCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:recipeCellIdentifier];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecipeCell" owner:self options:nil];
    if(nib.count > 0)
        {
        cell = self.customCell;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load CustomCell nib file!");
        }
    }

    // Set a number of properties of the custom cell
    // ...

    return cell;
```

`self.customCell` is an IBOutlet UITableViewCell that is bound to the cell in the actual nib file using File's owner (the nib contains only the UITableViewCell).

To me, this indicates that the nib does not load in time, i.e not until after the view has first appeared.

I have tried moving the nib loading to the `viewDidLoad` method, as well as forcing `reloadData` and `setNeedsDisplay` at the end of `viewWillAppear:` but to no avail.

What puzzles me is the fact that it all works as long as the table with the custom cells are not initially visible, but switched to after launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the nib loading, but lied within the storyboard. In the UIView, the setup was that only one of the two tableviews was visible at any given time. On launch, the table using standard cells was visible by default, but then logic in viewWillAppear: determined whether it should be hidden and the other one unhidden instead (based on a saved state).

Turns out that when I made both of them hidden on launch and used the saved state to unhide one of them, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subclassing UITableViewCell along with your nib file?

Cause you could try to use: (with RecipeCell as the name of your subclass)

```
RecipeCell *cell = (RecipeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:recipeCellIdentifier];

if ( !cell ) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecipeCell" owner:self options:nil];

    if(nib.count > 0)
    {
        self.customCell = [nib lastObject]; //Assuming you only have one top level object 
                                    //in the nib
        cell = self.customCell;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load CustomCell nib file!");
    }
}
```

Why would you use "customCell" as a property actually? You could just assign it like this and get rid of the self.customCell

```
cell = [nib lastObject];
```